# How subtraction of two select SQL statements works?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have two tables: purchase and sale.
Below query gives the difference between 'pqty' and 'sqty'

Can someone explain how below query works? What is stored in X,Y?
Please refer to the link for output of select queries. [Select queries for two tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DACZ.png)

```
select X.totalpqty - Y.totalsqty

from 

(select sum(pqty) as totalpqty from purchase where wasteid = 2)X, 

(select sum(sqty) as totalsqty from sale where recyclerid = 102001)Y;
```

Comment: What are u trying to accomplish here? Can you post some sample input and desired output so that I can try to help u..

Comment: Can you please refer to the link in the question. It has output of the select statements. I need help in understanding how the above query works.What is stored in X,Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given query creates 2 tables on the fly:

First on the fly table X:

```
select sum(pqty) as totalpqty from purchase where wasteid = 2
```

Creates a `table` X with only one value: the `totalpqty`, as sum of pqty's that have `wasteid=2`.

Second on the fly table Y:

```
select sum(sqty) as totalsqty from sale where recyclerid = 102001
```

Creates a `table` Y with only one value: the `totalsqty`, as sum of sqty's that have `recyclerid=102001`.

These 2 tables (X and Y) are not joined because there is no need to do so, as they only return a single value each. The cartesian product is just a single row with 2 columns:

- the sum of pqty's
- the sum of sqty's

Finally the main query, gets the 2 values that are returned by the 2 subqueries and performs the actual subtraction that is needed (`X.totalpqty - Y.totalsqty`).

Comment: Is there any official term for this process like join or union?

Comment: I would say that is just a shortened version of calling 2 aggregations. Alternatively, to produce the same result, you would execute the 2 queries one after the other storing the returned values in variables, and you would perform the subtraction on the variables.

Answer (score 0):

X and y are two subqueries result alias , which have two colums
totalpqty totalsqty